# How to change the color of last row of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created one webpage in ASP.NET with c#. I have taken one `GridView`.
I want to change or highlight the color of last row of `GridView`.

Please Refer below code :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.31.41.103/ORCL;User ID=RL_PET;Password=RL_PET;Unicode=True");
    con.Open();
    OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT NVL(MERGE,'GRAND_TOTAL') AS MERGE, COUNT(PALLET_NO) AS Total_Pallets , SUM(NET_WT) AS Net_Weight , SUM(GROSS_WT) AS Gross_Weight FROM WI_PALLET WHERE DATA_STS IN (2,3) AND TRANS_TYPE = 'P' GROUP BY ROLLUP (MERGE)", con);
    a.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Visible = true;
    con.Close();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {



     }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with `GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1]` you will get the last row of gridview, as already mentioned in  @Soner Gönül answer.

But instead of using the `RowDataBound` event, you need to use `PreRender`, here I added a class and by CSS you can do more styling stuff.

You can also use the [BackColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_BackColor) property and set any hex color code and make it highlighted

**Code Behind:**

```
  protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow getRow = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
        getRow.Attributes.Add("class", "highlighted");
        // or
         getRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#EE0000");
    }
```

**CSS :**  By adding [**! important**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) you can override the default styling

```
 .highlighted td
  {
     color:Red ! important;
     background-color: blue ! important;
  }
```

Comment: Working but CSS not able to override GridView format.

Answer (score 2):

Just use CSS:

```
tr:last-child { color: red; }
```

```css
tr:last-child { color:red; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Head1</td>
        <td>Head2</td>
        <td>Head3</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Added code so you can see it works.  If it doesn't, then you are overriding it in your CSS.

Comment: This is working now. Before it was not working reason behind that I have formatted GridView by selecting **Rainy Day scheme** from **Auto Format** option. That's why CSS changes was not reflecting. Is there any way to Highlight the last row with the formatted Gridview i.e. **Rainy Day scheme**

Comment: Inspect the css that is being applied to the row, and make yours more specific.  If your table has the id of `MyTable`, start there, with `#MyTable tr:last-row { color-red; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can find your last row using it's [`Rows` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as

```
gridView1.Rows[gridView1.Rows.Count - 1]
```

and you can set it's `BackColor`, `ForeColor` or `BorderColor` properties as;

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        gridView1.Rows[gridView1.Rows.Count - 1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        // Or you can set which color you want in Color enumeration.
    }   
}
```

Comment: getting this run time error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: @JayDesai Really? How many rows does Gridview has? It shouldn't throw this exception.

Comment: Yes. GridView has 11 rows.

Comment: @JayDesai Then `gridView1.Rows[10]` shouldn't throw this exception.